# React.ComponentProps can't infer type in interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, conditional-types

I'm confused about the React component props type infer, in the case below, the second param props can get the component props correctly, and throw type error as expected.

```
function myFunction<T extends React.ComponentType<any>> (Component: T, props: React.ComponentProps<T>) {
  // implementation
}

myFunction(Input, {accessKey: '', onChange: ''}) // error on onChange, Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

in another similar scenario，the Field interface can't resolve the props properly.

```
interface Field<T extends React.ComponentType<any> = React.ComponentType> {
  type: T;
  props: React.ComponentProps<T>;
}

const field: Field = {
  type: Input,
  props: { // can't infer the props of Input
    value: 2,
    onChange: '', // no error at all
  },
}
```

So is there any workaround to get the correct props of the runtime Component?

additionally, for now if I pass `typeof Input` as the generic, it works fine. But my purpose is ts could infer the type by the `type` attribute

```
const field: Field<typeof Input> = {
  type: Input,
  props: {
    value: 2,
    onChange: '', // throw error as expected
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've discovered that type-inference does not work for assignment to generic interface types. Most likely, you can wrap this up in a function and let function parameter inference do the heavy-lifting:

```
const C: React.FC<{ some: string; fields: number }> = () => <div>hello</div>;

interface Field<T extends React.ComponentType<any> = React.ComponentType> {
    type: T;
    props: React.ComponentProps<T>;
}

function createField<T extends React.ComponentType<any>>(
        type: T, 
        props: React.ComponentProps<T>): Field<T> {
    return {
        type,
        props
    }
}

const field = createField(C, { some: "hello", fields: 42 })
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwgLhgJQKYENhQHQDE4A8A3jBCALapLQBOAlmAOYDcMAZnagDYAmESYAK7kARqhowAvgD4YAXhgAKAJTzZBHnQBu0gBbcuIAgHpNO5gCgLDKOLaZUMXJ14EAKjFQAPW2D4oMLGw4CgAHcFQwKDcAT1DUAnQwGNkFNEwcEPJwsEjouNRZIgsYUpgoAqQ3SzKYUJoQUP4AjOCwiKiABQam92lLSSs2QTAsOnAYYBoMW2duHndPH0j-dKCsnLzY+MTk6WlFCviqgBo6nua1zPbcrou+5SQ51zcikrLpqEEaMBhi2tqR1QJ3eAPOjQgoKkFkGFlAkFgHHm8km03QsxcPEUcDOJDIlCQACJ9FxDISzkjeM0ACwAJikyiAA)

Comment: thx @spender, it may work fine for single field. What if i have a field list. It's still a problem

Comment: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwgLhgJQKYENhQHQDE4A8A3jBCALapLQBOAlmAOYDcMAZnagDYAmESYAK7kARqhowAvgD4YAXhgAKAJTzZBHnQBu0gBbcuIAgHpNO5gChQkWABEkaTDnzFSFVAEZqUek1YduPgAmAWExCRl5JVU5dTM9AyNTbWlLCzZBMCw6cBhgGgwoVFxOXggCABUYVAAPIrA+FAwsbDgKAAdwVDAoCoBPdtQCdDA+6WlFCxgYdvQadHIkAEEaeb7XKAGqGArWYEFoCgAFGhB2-ianVo6unpOz8orZGQAaC1UiKZgCqEEaMBmcwWlkkFis4Gg7FKjQU+UKxWhEEUAG0vp9ptNNoMkHA3hi8gcoMdTuckOj8VDAhcgniKWRKEgAOSM2nTSS09lor6YrZIWwvabGYwwLHbUUgNgwACSYHagig3IJh3I91JMHJ+ICZSQNMV03p22ZrKkHLeAF1lMwgA)

Comment: @user14863410 I fell flat on my face with this. I don't think TS has the power to infer a type T from two different props that rely on it in such a way. When I have time, I may ask my own question about this. I'll post back here if that happens.

Comment: thx for your comment, waiting for your new idea~